# i did not display books and also i got error Cannot set property 'getBooks' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

got error Cannot set property 'getBooks' of undefined

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

        myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
        console.log("BooksController loaded");
        $scope.getBooks = function(){
         $http.get('/api/books').then(function(response){
          $scope.books = response.data; 
        });
      }

    }]);
```

Comment: You're going to need to explain your problem more. This is very vague.

Comment: Post your HTML code

Comment: And the error means `$scope` is undefined. Debug to find out why.

Comment: Make sure you also defined the angular app itself, e.g. angular.module('myApp', []). The adding of [] tells angular this is the "app" (the "main" module).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly creating the Angular app module. In order to do so you need to pass an array (it can be empty) as the second parameter on your call to `angular.module`. Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```